# Vue.js ailed to resolve component: b-button

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to make a modal using bootstrap in vue.js.
I got the warning error

> '[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: b-button' and here is my code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button id="show-btn" @click="showModal">Open Modal</b-button>
    <b-button id="toggle-btn" @click="toggleModal">Toggle Modal</b-button>

    <b-modal ref="my-modal" hide-footer title="Using Component Methods">
      <div class="d-block text-center">
        <h3>Hello From My Modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <b-button class="mt-3" variant="outline-danger" block @click="hideModal">Close Me</b-button>
      <b-button class="mt-2" variant="outline-warning" block @click="toggleModal">Toggle Me</b-button>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.$refs['my-modal'].show()
      },
      hideModal() {
        this.$refs['my-modal'].hide()
      },
      toggleModal() {
        // We pass the ID of the button that we want to return focus to
        // when the modal has hidden
        this.$refs['my-modal'].toggle('#toggle-btn')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

i try to solve my problem by looking for the answer from their website bootstrap-vue.org but still it did not work on my project.

Comment: Probably installed Bootstrap wrongly somehow.

Comment: Have you read their docs on getting started: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs